# How can I skip a codepipeline stage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline

I am using AWS codepipeline as CI/CD pipeline tool. There are many stages in my yml file. The cloudformation reference for codepipeline is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-codepipeline-pipeline.html

```
...
Stages:
  - Name: ...
  Actions: ...

...
```

There are a list of stages in the pipeline but not all of them are required to run for every branch. How can I skip some of them based on branch name?

I tried below configuration which is passed by parameters via `aws cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides ...` command. It works but if I change the parameter in the deploy command, it shows `No changes to deploy.`. It seems that the template doesn't update the parameter change.

```
Parameters:
    ShouldRunTest:
       Type: String
       Default: false

Conditions:
    ShouldRunTest: !Equals [!Ref ShouldRunTest, "true"]

...


        - !If
          - ShouldRunTest
          - Name: test
            Actions:
              - Name: Deploy
                ActionTypeId:
                  Category: Deploy
                  Owner: AWS
                  Provider: CloudFormation
                  Version: 1
                InputArtifacts:
                  - Name: SourceOutput
                Configuration:
                  Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
                 
                  ActionMode: REPLACE_ON_FAILURE
                  RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineServiceRole.Arn
                  StackName: codeBuild
                RunOrder: 1
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Comment: Is it cloudformation yaml?

Comment: yes it is cloudformation yaml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip entire AWS CodePipeline actions or stages using conditions in your AWS CloudFormation template.

For example:

```
Conditions:

  HaveCodeDeployStage:
    !Not [ !Equals [!Ref CodeDeployAppName, ''] ]  

Resources:

  MyCodePipepline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      #... 
      Stages: 
        - !If
          - HaveCodeDeployStage
          - Name: DeployStage
            Actions: 
              - ActionTypeId: 
                  Category: Deploy
                  Owner: AWS
                  Provider: CodeDeployToECS
                  Version: 1
                  #....
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
        # ...
```

Comment: I tried your approach but got error `'null' values are not allowed in templates`. I have pasted my configuration in the question.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Hi. My approach works. But since you haven't provided any real code to work, there is nothing concrete to work with for me. So I also provided very generic answer.

Comment: Hi, I figured out why it fails. It's about my configuration issue. However, I passed the condition variable via `aws cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides ` command line parameter. It works the first time. When I change the parameter and deploy, it shows me `there is no change to deploy`. It seems that the condition doesn't take an update.